# source is not showing in imagebutton

Tags: android, image, background, imagebutton

i am trying to make an imageButton that will change state. so i made an xml file called "btn_marisa":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_marisa_bg_on" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_marisa_bg"/> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

than i made a layout with ImageButton, thats the code:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/marisa_logo"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_marisa"
    android:scaleType="fitStart" />
```

for some reason, in eclipse (in the graphical layout) it looks ok but when i install it on a phone only the background is showing.  it even changes state allright but i dont see the image that i need to see on the background.  its a button that has an icon and a background and i want only the background to change state.
what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: have u got any solution or not?

Answer (score 1):

It should work.

But first of all, make sure the source image `@drawable/marisa_logo` is smaller that the background images `btn_marisa_bg_on/btn_marisa_bg`, otherwise the image will overlap the whole background and you just won't be able to see when the background state will change.

Also, try to remove this attribute as well  `android:scaleType="fitStart"`, as this will strech the source image and again you won't be able to see the background.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that i see only the background.  i dont see the source image at all.

Comment: That is strange. I tried your example, only just with my images and it worked fine - I was able to see the source image, plus the background. Try to do a clean then: Project -> Clean, and for the sake of testing remove the adjustViewBounds and see if any effect.

Comment: its acting soooooo weird!!  any way, i worked around it...  i removed the image src and just put an ImageView right on it...  it looks great but its stupid...

Answer (score 0):

Try Button instead of ImageButton.
Delete android:src and leave just the android:background. 
This should be enough in most cases.
Try it and see if it displays what you wanted.

If you really should want background and source in an ImageButton first see if my suggestions work then add your modifications one by one.

Comment: maybe i wasn't clear in my question.  i see only the background.  if i will use Button i still will see only the background because Buttons have only background and not ImageSource. how is that helping in getting background and icon? Thanks.

Comment: And marisa_logo is the image and the drawable is the background?